# Android Studio: cannot resolve symbol VolumeProviderCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

In android studio, can't spot a way to import '**android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat**' .

Nevertheless, it does find and import both android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat and android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat correctly.

Fresh Android Studio install, with API level 21. Any idea what to try?

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat;
import android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat;
import android.util.Log;


public class InputTest Service{

    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService");
        mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0) //you simulate a player which plays something.
                .build());

        //this will only work on Lollipop and up, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224134
        VolumeProviderCompat myVolumeProvider =
                new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, /*max volume*/100, /*initial volume level*/50) {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                        
                /*
                -1 -- volume down
                1 -- volume up
                0 -- volume button released
                 */
                    }
                };

        mediaSession.setPlaybackToRemote(myVolumeProvider);
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaSession.release();
    }

}
```

Build gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you solve that problem? I am now facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct namespace for the depndency:

```
import androidx.media.VolumeProviderCompat;
```